# How to quickly update the classes of many elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I have a couple thousand elements on a page that should have their CSS class changed upon the pressing of a button.
Currently I have js code like the following:

```
for each (var id in list) {
    var element = document.querySelector('[data-id="' + id + ']');
    element.className = 'myClass';
}
```

In IE, this takes almost 20 seconds. I did some profiling, and it simply seems that the .className operation takes like half a millisecond; that along with garbage collection is what makes it take so long. I'm not sure if .className is causing a reflow or not.

Either way, how can I accomplish this task faster than I currently am?

Comment: Whats `for each` ???

Comment: It appears it is deprecated. Replace with for (x of y)

Comment: It never existed

Comment: It was introduced in Javascript 1.6, don't know when it was deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6

Comment: Oh right, that was never really a part of the language, im surprised that its actually been in the specs

Comment: 1. define `list`, 2.Do not use `for each..in` it's deprecated, 3. Do not gather your nodes by `[data-id="+'id'+"]` selector `[data-id]` is better than including each  value...in fact I don't even know for sure if it's valid with a variable...`:nth-of-type(2n+1)` is valid yet your selector is concatenated ...hm.

Comment: 1. This isn't my actual code, the looping is a little more involved, so I wanted to just give the gist of what I was doing: looping through integers that are IDs and getting the corresponding element from those IDs.
2. Yes, I realized that, see above comments. Thanks.
3. I'm not sure I follow. [data-id="n"] does work correctly as a selector. And I need to only update elements whose IDs are in the list. However, all the relevant elements will all be a child element of the same parent, so I could select them via parent element. But I don't believe that's the slow part.

Comment: What's *"a little more involved"* mean? If you haven't defined `list` then that loop doesn't work. I can create 3 separate snippets right away that'll work in any browser, that assigns a class to any reasonable group of nodes 10K+. I've tried ` [data-id="n"] ` and it works if the value was "n" It doesn't find `data-id="1"` or `data-id="m"` and `[data-id="+'id'+"]` doesn't do anything because `id` in the loop `for each...in` doesn't work for values like it used to in Chrome (that's a real browser btw). The added req for ids that match a list...what list? The `list` that you need to define?

Comment: @zer00ne, what I mean is that I abstracted my actual code to the simplest problem to avoid having to post a bunch of unnecessary code. The "list" in question should be an array of a few thousand integers. 

As far as "data-id" goes, here is it in use (I don't think I can post code-snippets in comments):
https://jsfiddle.net/zekehernandez/o0ezb4hq/6/

Comment: @ZekeHernandez It looks as if you need  a system of first determining exactly which numbers you want to toggle, then execute said toggling without doing it linearly one-by-one 1000 times. A search algorithm is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the CSS do all the hard work..

Just have some sort of parent, add a class to this and make your CSS target it.

eg.

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle("button-clicked");
}
```

```css
[data-id] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button-clicked [data-id] {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div data-id="1">One</div>
<div data-id="2">Two</div>
<div data-id="3">Three</div>
<div data-id="4">Four</div>
<div data-id="5">Five</div>

<button>Click Me</button>
```

If doing this CSS only is not an option, the best way to update the DOM is to do it detached,.  Here is an example that creates 10,000 div's, and on the button click it randomly toggles the selected class of each one, but before doing this will temporarily detach them from the DOM, and then reattach after flipping the classes.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

function addLine (txt) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = txt;
  div.classList.add("line");
  container.appendChild(div);
}

for (var l = 1; l <= 10000; l += 1) {
  addLine("This is Line " + l + ", and some extra text");
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function () {
  //temporally remove from DOM 
  container.parentNode.removeChild(container);  
  //all DOM methods here on conatiner should now be fast
  //as there is no UI updates required..
  var lines = container.querySelectorAll(".line");
  for (var l = 0; l < lines.length; l ++) {
    var e = lines[l];
    if (Math.random() > 0.5)
      e.classList.toggle("selected");
  };
  //Ok done, lets now put it back into the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(container); 
}
```

```css
.line {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.line.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle class</button>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: I really like this answer, but, and I'm sorry if this wasn't clear, I really do need each element to have its own class. This is because each element can be toggled itself by a different action.

Comment: Ok, updated answer to do it the detached DOM method too.

Comment: Hey Keith, I really appreciate you taking another crack at it. And this solutions works under a second in Chrome, which is great. But unfortunately in IE, I don't know how long it takes because after a couple of minutes I gave up (after trying a few times). It should be noted that clicking "Run code snippet" and creating the initial list is fast no matter what, it's the Toggle Class button. Which lines up with experience with this so far.

Comment: In fact, in my production code, I create the structure using a detached div and it works fast, I even tried recreating the div and attaching it to the DOM instead of updating className, but it's slower for whatever reason. I don't get it.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange.. Unfortunately I don't have IE11, I'm on Win10 and it's not installed,..  But running on Edge is super fast still. mmm..  You could try with say 100 div's to start, first to see if it works, 10,000 div's is maybe something IE11 can't hack detached or not.

Comment: @Keith **1.** [ctrl]+[alt]+[del] then click "Task Manager" **2.** Click "File" in the menubar **3.**  Pick "Run New Task" **4.** Enter: `iexplore.exe` **5.** The reason why IE11 is buried is because M$ is preparing its eventual demise x_x

Comment: @zer00ne  Ok, the problem for IE was a few syntax errors.   1. remove for DOM elements is not there so it's `container.parentNode.removeChild(container);` instead of just `container.remove()`.. And forEach is not supported for `querySelectorAll` so I've replaced with just a simple loop.   Running the above in IE11 even with 10,000 div's still works fine for me now.

Comment: Thanks @Keith, that made setting .className only take a couple hundreths of a millisecond! Unfortunately, the removing of the div takes around 8 seconds, and the re-appending of the div is taking over 20! But you answered my question about how to make setting the class name faster, so thanks again! I'll figure out if there are ways to optimize the other operations.

Comment: That's strange!!, running the above on IE11 on two machines here, clicking the toggle is instant.  And that is removing and appending!!..  I wonder if you have some strange extensions / plugin in your version of IE that's causing the issue?.  The fact you said IE hung initially, instead of throwing and error, I'm wondering if you have some sort of ES6 shim that runs really slow.

Comment: I'm sorry, my actual production code had long times for removing and appending. The code you pasted above works really fast!