# speed up HTML rendering with innerText

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

I have an HTML file that looks like so:

```
<pre>very long text (3 megabytes)</pre>
```

when loading this file, I see the text right away, no delay

the next step for me was to load the text using js. like so

```
<button type="button" id=set_text>set text </button>
<pre></pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var the_long_text //initialized with the same 3 megabytes test
    document.querySelector('#set_text').onclick=e=>document.querySelector('pre').innerText=the_long_text
</script>
```

now, the text loads much slower - when clicking the set_text button, the brower freezes for about 5 seconds and then renders the text in the pre.

my question is: is there any way to speed up the JS  version and make it as fast as the plain html?

edit: I am looking for a simple solution - just like the HTML solution. that rules out chunked loading. Also, is this a well known problem? if so what is the best practice to solve it?

Comment: You will want to progressively load the data in chunks, this will still be slow but faster than loading it all at once, and shouldn't freeze

Comment: You just have a really large amount of text.

Comment: One trick is to load the element while it's outside the DOM, then re-attach to the DOM.    Here is an example -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198917/how-to-quickly-update-the-classes-of-many-elements-in-javascript/49199077#49199077

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the element:

```
 <pre id="content" style="display:none">very long text (3 megabytes)</pre>
```

Then show it with:

```
 document.querySelector("content").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it did not work - I have the exact same 5 seconds freeze

Answer (score 1):

Here the text is loaded by chunks. It could take a little bit longer than with one set as in your example but without hanging.

```
<button type="button" id=set_text>set text </button>
<pre ></pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var longText = "..your long text...";
    document.querySelector('#set_text').onclick = e => load('');
    var chunkSize = 100000;
    var start = -chunkSize;
    function load(text) {
        var node = document.createTextNode(text);
        document.querySelector('pre').appendChild(node);

        if (start + chunkSize >= longText.length) {
            alert("Completed");
            return;
        }

        start += chunkSize;
        chunkSize = Math.min(chunkSize, longText.length - start);
        setTimeout(load, 0, longText.substr(start, chunkSize));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, that might work, but I am looking for something simpler (see my edit)

Comment: @yigal, I don't think that pure HTML-solution exists.

Comment: I tried that, but every time I call appendChild, It takes longer and longer

Comment: It's how the browser works. Try to play with `chunkSize` to find an optimal value between speed and hanging. Having `chunkSize = 500000` it takes about 4s with chunks and 3s without chunks on my laptop. The text size is quite atypical for standard tasks, so there is nothing surprising, even a text editor won't handle that without hanging for a while.

Comment: Your goal was to keep it from hanging, as I got it. So it does.