# Speed up large javascript DOM replace jquery $("#NODE").html("HTML")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am doing the following where response can be rather large html string

```
$("#register_container").html(response);
```

The problem is; it takes a long time with a large html (10-30 seconds). Is there a way to use virtual dom/other techniques to speed this up? Very little html changes when this happens, but I don't want to rewrite application logic to use react/vue as it would be a huge project.

Would react/vue be a good solution?

Comment: If it's taking 30 seconds to update the DOM I cannot imagine how ridiculously big that HTML string must be. There's no real way to speed up the weight of data on the client side. You could potentially return JSON instead of HTML and build the UI manually, but that's a lot of work for very little benefit. A better approach would simply to reduce the weight of data, through paging, filtering or searching.

Comment: Is there a way to diff the current html with the html that is about to be replaced and just update part of it?

Comment: Most likely yes, but again that would take a lot of time to write as it's not a common thing to need to do so I doubt it exists already. It probably also wouldn't address the issue, as at some point you have to create a DOM from the HTML you're interrogating, so you're back to the starting problem again

Comment: What about something like this? https://github.com/fiduswriter/diffDOM

Comment: Building the html as a detached DOM element will speed things up,  An example here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198917/how-to-quickly-update-the-classes-of-many-elements-in-javascript/49199077#49199077  The example is toggling CSS, but the same concept applies, basically build your DOM node detached.

Comment: Yep, that'll get you the diff. Now you need a way of implementing the changes it identifies. This is also assuming it can handle the massive HTML string any quicker, which is my main doubt.

Comment: You might be able to streamline the HTML, for example if you are using `<table>` - they are notoriously slow to update as the browser has to render the whole table to determine the column widths.

Comment: To give some background I have a point of sale app where their cart can be updated (changing quantities, prices..etc). Changing a price for example updates the total and subtotal. Each time an edit is made I send the change to the server then re-render the register how I showed in the example. I think diffing is probably not the solution. if I did a rewrite what would you suggest as a general approach? It get slow once they have about 100-200 items

Comment: I think you should at least check the timing on what Keith suggested — `detachedNode.html(response)` then attach the new node to register_container. Creating the DOM from the HTML should be faster with no rendering going on.

Comment: How would I do this using raw html (detached node)?

Comment: Is this what you mean? document.getElementById('register_container').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('register_container'));$("#sale-grid-big-wrapper").after(response)

Comment: The above code change made no performance difference. On my system it takes 3 seconds; on customers system it is 15-20 seconds